# How to move all controls on a form based on mouse movement at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

I am having a bit of a small issue performing a certain task in my winforms application.

I am basically attempting to recreate a "Top-View RTS Map", on a winform. In order to save memory, not all tiles of the "Map" are displayed on the screen. Only the ones that fit within the viewport. Therefore, I am trying to allow the user to perform a **pan/scroll** on the displayed tiles in order to navigate the entire map!

Right now, I am doing this by creating and displaying `GroupBox` controls dynamically at runtime. These represent the tiles...

I have created my own objects to support all of this (contains screen coordinates, Row and Col info, etc.)

Here is how I am currently accomplishing all of this, in pseudo-code:

**Creating the form, tiles and the map in general**

1. I create a winforms form that is 600px X 600px.
2. I create a new "Map" (using a `List<MapTile>`) that is 100 tiles by 100 tiles (for testing) on form load and save that into a variable.
3. I keep track of the displayed tiles via another list (or property that derives from the main list `bool MapTile.isDrawn`)
4. Each tile is **visually** made of a `GroupBox` control that is 100px
   X 100px (so [7 X 7] of them fit on screen)
5. To start, I find the center `MapTile` (tile [50, 50]) in the "Map", create the `GroupBox` for it and place that in the middle of the form,
6. I then add the other tiles/controls necessary to fill in the form (center - 3 tiles, center + 3 tiles (up, down, left, and right)).
7. Each tile, of course, subscribes to the proper mouse events to perform a drag
8. When the user mouse drags a tile, all other tiles being displayed follow suit/follow the leader by updating all "displayed tiles" coordinates to match the movement that was made by the "dragged" tile.

[image: how the map looks when the form loads for the first time]

**Managing Displayed Tiles**

1. While the `GroupBox` tiles are being dragged/moved, I perform a check to see if the tiles that are on the outer edge of the viewport are within its bounds.
2. If, as an example, the top-left-most tile's **right** edge falls outside the bounds of the left edge of the viewport, I remove the entire left column tiles, and add the entire right column tiles programmatically. The same goes all directions (up, down, left and right).

So far, this works fine as long as I don't go too fast... however, when I drag the tiles "too fast" passed an outer edge (e.g.: where point 2 ci-dessus would apply), it seems that the application is unable to keep up because it doesn't add the column or row where they should be on the form, and other times, it does not have time to remove all controls of a row or column and I end up with controls that are still on the screen when they shouldn't be there. At that point the entire grid/map is off balance and stops working as intended because either the events that should fire on one edge don't (the tiles are not present) and/or there are now multiple controls with the same name on the form and the removal or referencing fails...

[image: what the map looks like when it fails]

While I am well aware that winforms is not designed to perform intensive GPU/GDI operations, you would think that something this simple would still be easily do-able in winforms?

How would I go about making this more responsive at runtime? Here's my entire set of code:

**Form code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RTSAttempt
{
public enum DrawChange
{
    None,
    Rem_First_Draw_Last,
    Rem_Last_Draw_First
};

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string selected { get; set; }
    private int _xPos { get; set; }
    private int _yPos { get; set; }
    private bool _dragging { get; set; }
    public List<MapTile> mapTiles { get; set; }
    public List<MapTile> drawnTiles { get { return this.mapTiles.Where(a => a.Drawn == true).ToList(); } }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //init globals
        this.selected = "";
        this._dragging = false;
        this.mapTiles = new List<MapTile>();

        //for testing, let's do 100 x 100 map
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
            {
                MapTile tile = new MapTile(x, i, false, -1, -1, false);
                this.mapTiles.Add(tile);
            }
        }

        GenerateStartupTiles();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used to generate the first set of map tiles on screen and dispaly them.
    /// </summary>
    private void GenerateStartupTiles()
    {

        //find center tile based on list size
        double center = Math.Sqrt(this.mapTiles.Count);

        //if not an even number of map tiles, we take the next one after the root.
        if (this.mapTiles.Count % 2 != 0)
            center += 1;

        //now that we have the root, we divide by 2 to get the true center tile.
        center = center / 2;

        //get range of tiles to display...
        int startat = (int)center - 3;
        int endat = (int)center + 3;

        //because the screen is roughly 600 by 600, we can display 7 X 7 tiles...
        for (int row = 0; row < 7; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 7; col++)
            {
                //get the current tile we are trying to display.
                MapTile tile = mapTiles.First(a => a.Row == (startat + row) && a.Col == (startat + col));

                //create and define the GroupBox control we use to display the tile on screen.
                GroupBox pct = new GroupBox();
                pct.Width = 100;
                pct.Height = 100;

                //find start position on screen
                if (row == 0)
                    pct.Top = -50;
                else
                    pct.Top = -50 + (row * 100);

                if (col == 0)
                    pct.Left = -50;
                else
                    pct.Left = -50 + (col * 100);

                tile.X = pct.Left;
                tile.Y = pct.Top;

                pct.Name = tile.ID;
                pct.Tag = Color.LightGray;

                //subscribe to necessary events.
                pct.MouseEnter += Pct_MouseEnter;
                pct.MouseLeave += Pct_MouseLeave;
                pct.Click += Pct_Click;
                pct.Paint += Pct_Paint;
                pct.MouseDown += Pct_MouseDown;
                pct.MouseMove += Pct_MouseMove;
                pct.MouseUp += Pct_MouseUp;
                pct.Text = tile.DisplayID;
                //add the tile to the screen
                this.Controls.Add(pct);
                //set the tile to Drawn mode...
                tile.Drawn = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Pct_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //self explanatory
        if (this._dragging)
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
            this._dragging = false;
        }
    }

    private void Pct_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var c = sender as GroupBox;
        if (!_dragging || null == c) return;

        //get original position, and movement step/distance for calcs.
        int newTop = e.Y + c.Top - _yPos;
        int newLeft = e.X + c.Left - _xPos;
        int movedByX = this.drawnTiles.First(a => a.ID.ToString() == c.Name).X;
        int movedByY = this.drawnTiles.First(a => a.ID.ToString() == c.Name).Y;
        movedByY = newTop - movedByY;
        movedByX = newLeft - movedByX;
        //perform all tile movements here
        MoveAllTiles(movedByX, movedByY);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// This method performs all tile movements on screen, and updates the listing properly.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="X">int - the amount fo pixels that the dragged tile has moved horizontally</param>
    /// <param name="Y">int - the amount fo pixels that the dragged tile has moved vertically</param>
    private void MoveAllTiles(int X, int Y)
    {
        //used to single out the operation, if any, that we need to do after this move (remove row or col, from edges)
        DrawChange colAction = DrawChange.None;
        DrawChange rowAction = DrawChange.None;

        //move all tiles currently being displayed first... 
        for (int i = 0; i < this.drawnTiles.Count; i++)
        {
            //first, determine new coordinates of tile.
            drawnTiles[i].Y = drawnTiles[i].Y + Y;
            drawnTiles[i].X = drawnTiles[i].X + X;

            //find the control
            GroupBox tmp = this.Controls.Find(drawnTiles[i].ID, true)[0] as GroupBox;

            //perform screen move
            tmp.Top = drawnTiles[i].Y;
            tmp.Left = drawnTiles[i].X;
            tmp.Refresh();
        }

        //dtermine which action to perform, if any...
        if (drawnTiles.Last().Y > this.Height)
            rowAction = DrawChange.Rem_Last_Draw_First;
        else if ((drawnTiles.First().Y + 100) < 0)
            rowAction = DrawChange.Rem_First_Draw_Last;
        else
            rowAction = DrawChange.None;

        if ((drawnTiles.First().X + 100) < 0)
            colAction = DrawChange.Rem_First_Draw_Last;
        else if (drawnTiles.Last().X > this.Width)
            colAction = DrawChange.Rem_Last_Draw_First;
        else
            colAction = DrawChange.None;

        //get currently dispalyed tile range.
        int startRow = this.drawnTiles.First().Row;
        int startCol = this.drawnTiles.First().Col;
        int endRow = this.drawnTiles.Last().Row;
        int endCol = this.drawnTiles.Last().Col;

        //perform the correct action(s), if necessary.

        if (rowAction == DrawChange.Rem_First_Draw_Last)
        {
            //remove the first row of tiles from the screen
            this.drawnTiles.Where(a => a.Row == startRow).ToList().ForEach(a => { a.Drawn = false; this.Controls.RemoveByKey(a.ID); this.Refresh(); });

            //add the last row of tiles on screen... 
            List<MapTile> TilesToAdd = this.mapTiles.Where(a => a.Row == endRow + 1 && a.Col >= startCol && a.Col <= endCol).ToList();
            int newTop = this.drawnTiles.Last().Y + 100;
            for (int i = 0; i < TilesToAdd.Count; i++)
            {
                int newLeft = (i == 0 ? drawnTiles.First().X : drawnTiles.First().X + (i * 100));
                //create and add the new tile, and set it to Drawn = true.
                GroupBox pct = new GroupBox();
                pct.Name = TilesToAdd[i].ID.ToString();
                pct.Width = 100;
                pct.Height = 100;
                pct.Top = newTop;
                TilesToAdd[i].Y = newTop;
                pct.Left = newLeft;
                TilesToAdd[i].X = newLeft;
                pct.Tag = Color.LightGray;
                pct.MouseEnter += Pct_MouseEnter;
                pct.MouseLeave += Pct_MouseLeave;
                pct.Click += Pct_Click;
                pct.Paint += Pct_Paint;
                pct.MouseDown += Pct_MouseDown;
                pct.MouseMove += Pct_MouseMove;
                pct.MouseUp += Pct_MouseUp;
                pct.Text = TilesToAdd[i].DisplayID;
                this.Controls.Add(pct);
                TilesToAdd[i].Drawn = true;
            }
        }
        else if (rowAction == DrawChange.Rem_Last_Draw_First)
        {
            //remove last row of tiles
            this.drawnTiles.Where(a => a.Row == endRow).ToList().ForEach(a => { a.Drawn = false; this.Controls.RemoveByKey(a.ID); this.Refresh(); });

            //add first row of tiles
            List<MapTile> TilesToAdd = this.mapTiles.Where(a => a.Row == startRow - 1 && a.Col >= startCol && a.Col <= endCol).ToList();
            int newTop = this.drawnTiles.First().Y - 100;
            for (int i = 0; i < TilesToAdd.Count; i++)
            {
                int newLeft = (i == 0 ? drawnTiles.First().X : drawnTiles.First().X + (i * 100));
                //create and add the new tile, and set it to Drawn = true.
                GroupBox pct = new GroupBox();
                pct.Name = TilesToAdd[i].ID.ToString();
                pct.Width = 100;
                pct.Height = 100;
                pct.Top = newTop;
                TilesToAdd[i].Y = newTop;
                pct.Left = newLeft;
                TilesToAdd[i].X = newLeft;
                pct.Tag = Color.LightGray;
                pct.MouseEnter += Pct_MouseEnter;
                pct.MouseLeave += Pct_MouseLeave;
                pct.Click += Pct_Click;
                pct.Paint += Pct_Paint;
                pct.MouseDown += Pct_MouseDown;
                pct.MouseMove += Pct_MouseMove;
                pct.MouseUp += Pct_MouseUp;
                pct.Text = TilesToAdd[i].DisplayID;
                this.Controls.Add(pct);
                TilesToAdd[i].Drawn = true;
            }
        }

        if (colAction == DrawChange.Rem_First_Draw_Last)
        {
            //remove the first column of tiles
            this.drawnTiles.Where(a => a.Col == startCol).ToList().ForEach(a => { a.Drawn = false; this.Controls.RemoveByKey(a.ID); this.Refresh(); });


            //add the last column of tiles
            List<MapTile> TilesToAdd = this.mapTiles.Where(a => a.Col == endCol + 1 && a.Row >= startRow && a.Row <= endRow).ToList();
            int newLeft = this.drawnTiles.Last().X + 100;
            for (int i = 0; i < TilesToAdd.Count; i++)
            {
                int newTop = (i == 0 ? drawnTiles.First().Y : drawnTiles.First().Y + (i * 100));
                //create and add the new tile, and set it to Drawn = true.
                GroupBox pct = new GroupBox();
                pct.Name = TilesToAdd[i].ID.ToString();
                pct.Width = 100;
                pct.Height = 100;
                pct.Top = newTop;
                TilesToAdd[i].Y = newTop;
                pct.Left = newLeft;
                TilesToAdd[i].X = newLeft;
                pct.Tag = Color.LightGray;
                pct.MouseEnter += Pct_MouseEnter;
                pct.MouseLeave += Pct_MouseLeave;
                pct.Click += Pct_Click;
                pct.Paint += Pct_Paint;
                pct.MouseDown += Pct_MouseDown;
                pct.MouseMove += Pct_MouseMove;
                pct.MouseUp += Pct_MouseUp;
                pct.Text = TilesToAdd[i].DisplayID;
                this.Controls.Add(pct);
                TilesToAdd[i].Drawn = true;
            }
        }
        else if (colAction == DrawChange.Rem_Last_Draw_First)
        {
            //remove last column of tiles
            this.drawnTiles.Where(a => a.Col == endCol).ToList().ForEach(a => { a.Drawn = false; this.Controls.RemoveByKey(a.ID); this.Refresh(); });

            //add first column of tiles
            List<MapTile> TilesToAdd = this.mapTiles.Where(a => a.Col == startCol - 1 && a.Row >= startRow && a.Row <= endRow).ToList();
            int newLeft = this.drawnTiles.First().X - 100;
            for (int i = 0; i < TilesToAdd.Count; i++)
            {
                int newTop = (i == 0 ? drawnTiles.First().Y : drawnTiles.First().Y + (i * 100));
                //create and add the new tile, and set it to Drawn = true.
                GroupBox pct = new GroupBox();
                pct.Name = TilesToAdd[i].ID.ToString();
                pct.Width = 100;
                pct.Height = 100;
                pct.Top = newTop;
                TilesToAdd[i].Y = newTop;
                pct.Left = newLeft;
                TilesToAdd[i].X = newLeft;
                pct.Tag = Color.LightGray;
                pct.MouseEnter += Pct_MouseEnter;
                pct.MouseLeave += Pct_MouseLeave;
                pct.Click += Pct_Click;
                pct.Paint += Pct_Paint;
                pct.MouseDown += Pct_MouseDown;
                pct.MouseMove += Pct_MouseMove;
                pct.MouseUp += Pct_MouseUp;
                ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
                tt.SetToolTip(pct, pct.Name);
                pct.Text = TilesToAdd[i].DisplayID;
                this.Controls.Add(pct);
                TilesToAdd[i].Drawn = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Pct_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //self explanatory
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;
        _dragging = true;
        _xPos = e.X;
        _yPos = e.Y;
    }

    private void Pct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //changes the border color to reflect the selected tile... 
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selected))
        {
            if (this.Controls.Find(selected, true).Length > 0)
            {
                GroupBox tmp = this.Controls.Find(selected, true)[0] as GroupBox;
                ControlPaint.DrawBorder(tmp.CreateGraphics(), tmp.ClientRectangle, Color.LightGray, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
            }
        }

        GroupBox pct = sender as GroupBox;
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(pct.CreateGraphics(), pct.ClientRectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
        this.selected = pct.Name;
    }

    private void Pct_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //draws the border based on the correct tag.
        GroupBox pct = sender as GroupBox;
        Color clr = (Color)pct.Tag;
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, pct.ClientRectangle, clr, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
    }

    private void Pct_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //draws the border back to gray, only if this is not the selected tile...
        GroupBox pct = sender as GroupBox;
        if (this.selected != pct.Name)
        {
            pct.Tag = Color.LightGray;
            pct.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private void Pct_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //draws a red border around the tile to show which tile the mouse is currently hovering on...
        GroupBox pct = sender as GroupBox;
        pct.Tag = Color.Red;
        pct.Refresh();
    }
}
}
```

**`MapTile` object**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RTSAttempt
{

public class MapTile
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the row of the tile on the map
    /// </summary>
    public int Row { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the column of the tile on the map
    /// </summary>
    public int Col { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the ID of this tile ([-1,-1], [0,0], [1,1], etc
    /// </summary>
    public string ID { get { return "Tile_" + this.Row + "_" + this.Col; } }

    public string DisplayID { get { return this.Row + ", " + this.Col; } }
    /// <summary>
    /// If this tile is currently selected or clicked.
    /// </summary>
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the X screen coordinates of the tile
    /// </summary>
    public int X { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the Y screen coordinates of the tile
    /// </summary>
    public int Y { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents whether this tile is currently being drawn on the screen. 
    /// </summary>
    public bool Drawn { get; set; }


    public MapTile(int idCol = -1, int idRow = -1, bool selected = false, int screenX = -1, int screenY = -1, bool drawn = false)
    {
        this.Col = idCol;
        this.Row = idRow;
        this.Selected = selected;
        this.X = screenX;
        this.Y = screenY;
        this.Drawn = drawn;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        MapTile tmp = obj as MapTile;
        if (tmp == null)
            return false;

        return this.ID == tmp.ID;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.ID.GetHashCode();
    }


}
}
```

Comment: I'd create the grid (using DataGridView, TableLayoutPanel, GDI+, or whatever) and then in the drag and drop, just calculate the new indexes and update the indexes, without moving the grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create the grid using (`DataGridView`, `TableLayoutPanel`, `GDI+`, or whatever) and then in the drag and drop, just calculate the new indexes and update the indexes, without moving the grid.

**Example**

The following example shows how to do it using a `TableLayoutPanel`:

- Assign a fixed size to cells
- Build the grid to fill the form
- When form resizes, rebuild the grid
- In mouse down capture the mouse down point and current top left index of grid
- In mouse move, calculate the new index based on mouse movement and update index
- In cell paint of the panel, draw the indexes

Here is the code:

```
int topIndex = 0, leftIndex = 0;
int originalLeftIndex = 0, originalTopIndex = 0;
int cellSize = 100;
Point p1;
TableLayoutPanel panel;
void LayoutGrid()
{
    panel.SuspendLayout();
    var columns = (ClientSize.Width / cellSize) + 1;
    var rows = (ClientSize.Height / cellSize) + 1;
    panel.RowCount = rows;
    panel.ColumnCount = columns;
    panel.ColumnStyles.Clear();
    panel.RowStyles.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
        panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, cellSize));
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        panel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, cellSize));
    panel.Width = columns * cellSize;
    panel.Height = rows * cellSize;
    panel.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;
    panel.ResumeLayout();
}
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    panel = new MyGrid();
    this.Controls.Add(panel);
    LayoutGrid();
    panel.MouseDown += Panel_MouseDown;
    panel.MouseMove += Panel_MouseMove;
    panel.CellPaint += Panel_CellPaint;
}
protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSizeChanged(e);
    if (panel != null)
        LayoutGrid();
}
private void Panel_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
{
    var g = e.Graphics;
    TextRenderer.DrawText(g, $"({e.Column + leftIndex}, {e.Row + topIndex})",
        panel.Font, e.CellBounds, panel.ForeColor);
}
private void Panel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        var dx = (e.Location.X - p1.X) / cellSize;
        var dy = (e.Location.Y - p1.Y) / cellSize;
        leftIndex = originalLeftIndex - dx;
        topIndex = originalTopIndex - dy;
        panel.Invalidate();
    }
}
private void Panel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    p1 = e.Location;
    originalLeftIndex = leftIndex;
    originalTopIndex = topIndex;
}
```

To prevent flicker:

```
public class MyGrid : TableLayoutPanel
{
    public MyGrid()
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is nice, and "sorta" does what I want it to do... but while it is a solution to the functional concept I am trying to achieve, it is still outside the scope of the question, which is: how do I make this happen properly using the format provided? A downfall to your solution right now for example is that it goes beyond the map/does not stop at 0 (-1 and more), and as well, it does not visually show the map moving per say other than numbers changing... the other way/original way, shows movement...

Comment: *It goes beyond the map/does not stop at 0* → Then stop it easily by checking  the index value.

Comment: *It does not visually show the map moving* If you prefer it to move, just move the `TableLayoutPanel` and get rid of group of GroupBoxes.

Comment: I personally will use a solution based on a single custom drawn control. All rendering will be done based on a model, in `OnPain` method of my custom control. But the post is long enough. I tried to explain the idea by a simple code I'm sure you get the idea :) you probably can do the same thing with more performance and better visual support in a custom control rendered by GDI+.

Answer (score 1):

So, for anyone trying to do this, as a concept, here is how to fix this issue:

1. Instead of only drawing 1 row/col extra outside the viewport to save memory, draw the entire viewport's worth of cells in every direction of the edges (up, down, left and right)... for example, if your viewport can hold 5 tiles (5 X 5 = 25), then you need to draw 5 X 5 outside the viewport in every other direction (25 X 4 = 100)...
2. When the mouse is being dragged, just move the controls that are already on the form/control/"drawn"... this way, the user cannot, while dragging, go outside the bounds of the existing tiles... example, if they reach the outer right edge with the mouse, while dragging the left-most tile, the tiles to show on the left already exist! So we are just "following the mouse", which is not an issue if the controls are already there/there is no "loss/issues" because we are not removing or adding any tiles at this point...
3. When the user stops dragging the selected tile around (`onMouseUp`), THEN we re-calculate the tiles that need to be drawn and those that don't... so we only redraw (add and/or remove controls where necessary) the entire set of "drawn" tiles after the user is done dragging...

With this method, you remove any "missplaced" controls, double generation of controls, controls missing and any other issue that arises when the mouse moves too fast for the "Calculate drawn tiles" code to execute. You also "see" the map moving around as you drag, and you always have the correct tiles drawn on the screen! Problem solved!

However, I did find that when I used a `UserControl` instead of the form itself, the controls draw and update much faster and better than if I just add them to the form itself... therefore, I have accepted the answer that outlines that aspect as the actual answer, and placed this here for anyone else in future that might wonder how to do this as a concept.